# Cross platform tools for mobile: When it will be useful?

Tags: java, android, ios, cordova

**Question:** When can I say cross platform tools can handle this type of development..?

Below are **NOT** questions to answer. These are just guides why I raise the question to avoid too long description.

1. For **game** development :

   - Are tools (i.e phoneGap, widgetPad etc...) alike (given these terms...openGL, xna, 2d, 3d and others..) sufficient enough for game development?
2. For **Applications** development :

   - Like in native android, can the cross platform tools would still be able to do the same as native java does? i.e. Accessing notifications, contacts etc..

Answer (score 1):

I would say at the current time, it is not ready for **1** and will really not be anytime soon (without undo trouble to the developer that in the end is a setback).

As for **2**, it can and is ready for your question immediately. Sure, you have to still call the native Java or Obj-C for some truly native features, but this can all be done from within the Javascript/HTML interacting into the Java domain. This, they call plugins, and albeit a nightmare to upgrade at some times(pre 1.9.0, but anything developed after 2.0.0 won't have those issues to deal with (mostly))

Answer (score 0):

Check out ADF Mobile just released on Monday (Oct 22, 2012) for business software. It provides Android and iOS solution and it is Java based. The info can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adf-mobile-096323.html

Answer (score 0):

With the platform and device diversity reining the mobile landscape, cross-platform app development has emerged as a commercially viable option. Here are the the Top 10 Cross Platform Mobile App Development Tools
https://www.rootinfosol.com/top-10-cross-platform-mobile-app-development-tools